# Docusaurus CNAME file is deleted after each build

Tags: github-pages, cname, docusaurus

I am building a website with Docusaurus with a custom domain name and hosted with GitHub pages, everything is working fine. But after I run `docusaurus-build` the CNAME file gets deleted. Causing my website to become unreachable from my custom domain.

What ever I try re-adding the CNAME file does not help it gets deleted after each build.

I understand that docusaurus replaces all the files in the build directory, but how can prevent it from deleting my CNAME file?

My siteConfig file looks like this:

```
const siteConfig = {
  title: 'Harry Stylesheet' /* title for your website */,
  tagline: 'My Website',
  url: 'http://harrystylesheet.com' /* your website url */,
  baseUrl: '/' /* base url for your project */,

  // Used for publishing and more
  projectName: 'harrystylesheet.github.io',
  organizationName: 'Harry Stylesheet',

    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

For now my sollution is to re=configue my GitHub pages settings in my repository, so anyone else running into the same problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docusaurus maintainer here!

### Docusaurus >=2 (update 2021 Nov)

Add the CNAME file directly into the static folder. Refer to the docs - https://docusaurus.io/docs/deployment#docusaurusconfigjs-settings

### Docusaurus 1

You're right in saying that everything in `build` will be generated and you can't add custom files to it. What you can do is to add the `cname` field to `siteConfig.js` file as mentioned in the docs [here](https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/site-config#cname-string).

For Docusaurus docs: https://github.com/facebook/Docusaurus/blob/master/v1/website/siteConfig.js#L18

So for your case, you could add `cname: 'harrystylesheet.com'` to your `siteConfig.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse this worked, but I did not add the **http://** in front of the url so `cname: 'harrystylesheet.com'` works fine for me.

Comment: Doesn't work on v2. Tried to add cname on docusaurus.config.js failed on validation

Comment: @NoloMokgosi for Docusaurus v2 just add the CNAME file directly into the static folder. Refer to the docs - https://docusaurus.io/docs/deployment#docusaurusconfigjs-settings. Have updated the answer

Comment: For anyone reading this- it's not explained in the linked docs, but the CNAME file simply needs to contain the custom URL you're trying to use for the site.